# Swift decode object with some common elements, and some changing

Tags: json, swift, codable

There are a few different JSON objects that could be returned from a single endpoint. There will always be some elements in the object, including a type, and I know all the types. But then the different objects could have some different elements. Here's some example JSON

```
// Story.json

{
    "id": 1,
    "time": 1314211127,
    "type": "story",
    "title": "Awesome story",
    "comment_count": 36
}
```

```
// Ad.json
{
    "id": 2,
    "time": 1316142113127,
    "type": "ad",
    "image_url": "https://someurl.com/",
    "tracking_id": 67814
}
```

```
// Comment.json
{
    "id": 3,
    "time": 131448227,
    "type": "comment",
    "text": "A comment",
    "parent_id": 1
}
```

So you can see that there's comment elements like `id`, `time`, and `comment`. However, based on the type, the additional elements are different. I'm getting confused trying to decode this. So far I have:

```
enum ItemType: String, Decodable {
    case story
    case ad
    case comment
}

protocol Item: Decodable {

    var id: Int { get }
    var time: Int? { get }
    var type: ItemType { get }

}

struct AnyItem: Item {

    let id: Int
    let time: Int?
    let type: ItemType

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, time, type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        time = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .time)
        type = try container.decode(ItemType.self, forKey: .type)
        // Then I'm assuming switch on the type here
        switch type {
            // don't know where to go from here...
        }
    }

}
```

I guess I need other types conforming to `Item` such as `StoryItem`, `AdItem`, `CommentItem`. Then, because the endpoint can return all of these items in one response, I can store it in an array of type `[Item]`. I just can't figure out how to decode all those types in one response.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An easy method would be to use `optionals` for the optional keys and they'll be ignored while decoding. Since you already have the type, you can know for sure which keys are gonna be present or you can just unwrap them.

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let time: Int
    let type: ItemType
    let text: String?
    let title: String? // and all other optional properties
}
```